# Turning this code into a nested loop

Tags: c++

I am supposed to write a program, that will ask a user to input a number and then display all the perfect squares starting from 1 to the input number^2. I have written this program, but I was asked to put it in a nested loop. The problem is, I don't know how I could turn this into nested loop format. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is my program so far:

```
int input;
int number = 1;
cout << "Enter a number: ";
cin >> input;
if(input > 1) {
    cout << "The perfect squares are: ";
    do {
        cout << number*number;
        number++;
        input--;
        if(input == 1) {
            cout << " and "; }
        else {cout << ", ";}
    }while(input > 1);
    cout << number*number << ".";
}
else if(input == 1) {
    cout << "1";
}
else {
    cout << "None.";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does it need to be a nested loop? This can be done using a simple `for` loop.

```
unsigned int input;
cout << "Enter a number: ";
cin >> input;

for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= input; ++i)
{
    cout << i << " squared is " << i * i << endl;
}
```

[Working demo](http://ideone.com/idV5yS)

The `while` loop equivalent would be

```
unsigned int input;
cout << "Enter a number: ";
cin >> input;

unsigned int i = 1;
while(i <= input)
{
    cout << i << " squared is " << i * i << endl;
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: I was specifically asked to use a nested loop, I'm not sure why. We also have not covered for loops yet. Thank you for this example! I am supposed to format the output like so (for example, if 5 is input): "1, 4, 16 and 25"

Comment: Maybe the professor wants to ask for a number more than 1 time looping until the user enters something other than a positive integer greater than 0.

Comment: I've changed my while loop to be simpler, like Cyber's, and I will try what drescherjm suggested. Thank you both for your help!